# OSGi shell with command history, line edit and not only basic commands

Tags: shell, osgi

When I try do search the Internet about it, it looks like almost nobody talks about it, like it would work for everyone or nobody cares.

I have installed Karaf and I see that it has a very good shell with something like 100 useful for me commands. But when I use Felix+gogo or Equinix+gogo:

- line editing doesn't exist,
- there is no command history
- and when in on Felix there is even no such simple and useful command like Equinox's *package* or Karaf's *package:exports*.

Is this only my problem or this is the way gogo works? How can I get normal, XXI century, shell in Felix or Equinox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the standard behavior. 
The Karaf Shell is an improved GogoShell with lots of enhancements. 
Like the history and such. 
For package:export etc. find the according bundles of the Karaf project and try if you can use them in your project. It's just a Bundle that provides those commands. Or switch to Karaf if you like.

Comment: I tried, but there is a mountain of dependencies, it's much easier to simply use Karaf distribution, as you said. So this basic shell is a standard, thx.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the lack of command line editing  is that it generally requires native code. Obviously you do not want to add native code dependencies to frameworks. The design scope of Gogo was an absolute minimal shell that could run everywhere, also embedded.

It is quite easy to wrap Gogo in a JLine shell. This is basically what the Karaf people have done though this makes it a considerably heavier resource than the built-in shell.

OSGi is all about dependencies. If you're the framework, you want to aggressively minimize them. That said, the plugin model works fine, just add a shell bundle.